# Making Documentation Compulsory In Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, javadoc

Is there a way to make documentation compulsory in a class,in android studio.?

Comment: I can only think of adding verification tools to the check-in process, so that code won't be accepted if documentation (you'll have to define what "documentation" is yourselfs, of course) is not present.

Comment: Not the right tool or place in the process.  Do you really want your code not to compile until you've documented it all?  Not to debug?  The right place for this is in code review, possibly with some help from an automated checkin script.

Comment: @KenY-N please can you give an example of a verification tool i can use?

Comment: @GabeSechan yes i don't want the code to compile, if there is no document provided. like the  deprecated annotation that provides message,replacewith and level.

Comment: @GabeSechan not necessary compulsory to write the full document, but atleast right a little about what you did before you build.

Comment: Yeah, Gary's going to annoy your devs to no end, and ends up with them blowing off documentation with the bare minimum you get their work done. It's too high a burden. That burden should come before it's committed to the repo, not before they test something out

Answer (score 0):

One can use [Checkstyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_javadoc.html) to enforce JavaDoc comments. Also see [AbstractJavadocCheck](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/javadoc/AbstractJavadocCheck.html).